# How to read an array and show it in a modal: PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My code only show first row in my modal. I don't know how to show in modal all rows:

PHP:

```
$sql2="SELECT nombre, dias, COUNT(dias) as count FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios.id = '$id_user';
if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->query($sql2)){
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="'.$array["nombre"].'" data-dia="'.$array["dias"].'" href="#">'.$array["count"].'</a>';
}
```

HTML & Javascript

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">;
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">;
<div class="modal-content">;
<div class="modal-header">;
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>;
<h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>;
</div>;
<div class="modal-body">;
<form class="form-inline">;
<div class="form-group">;
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">;
</div>;
<div class="pull-right">;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>;
</div>;
</form>;
</div>;
<div class="modal-footer">;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-active" data-dismiss="modal">Tancar</button>;
</div>;
</div>;
</div>;
</div>; 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
var dia = button.data('dia') 

var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text('Dies personals: ' + recipient)
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(dia)
})
</script>
```

This code work, but only show in modal 1 DATE, and i want to show all DATES from a USER

Comment: you are sending one data here.. it will go one data only -> data-whatever="'.$array["nombre"].'

Comment: keeping name array doesn't mean.. collection of data will go and sit in the place.